# Plone usefulness for Backend Development

Tags: mongodb, web, server, plone

We have a python based server that uses mongodb database. Our server programs uses RabbitMQ to exchange request/reply packets with many Android apps and perform actions accordingly. In addition to this, now we also need to create a web portal for the admin staff to let them manipulate the database, upload/download files, view data/statistics and trigger actions for android clients. So, the database is going to be common for the portal and the existing server programs.

For the web portal development, I got a recommendation for using Plone. We are comfortable in using traditional Node.js. Could anybody guide me on the use of Plone within this context. Is plone able to communicate with mongodb and existing server side programs?

Comment: I posted a link to your question on our forum, at https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-plone-usefulness-for-backend-development/4222 (For this type of complex question you should stick with our forum... it's not going to be a very cut and dried answer.)

Comment: Plone is being used successfully as a back end storage service with Angular and React and the Plone REST API.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular someone recommended Plone for this purpose? The requirements are a little low on detail and perhaps there is something missing which might explain why someone recommended Plone or using a CMS at all?

Comment: The plone was suggested to reduce the designing of the components from scratch

Answer (score 1):

Plone is a CMS designed around managing web based content and is tightly integrated for storage of its data in the ZODB, a NoSQL database. If data is very custom and isn't all about webpages and website nagivation etc, or if you have a need for the data to live in a different kind of DB then Plone probably isn't the right tool for you. This isn't to say it can't be made to do these these things but you would have to learn a lot about it's internals to make it do these things.

Comment: Okay, in that case what other CMS based web development platform do you suggest?

Comment: If you have determined that you need a CMS, then Plone is certainly one of the best options out there with a great track record.